# Fetching data at once and put in two different div

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, mysql

I have been trying to fetch chat messages between two users and want to put them in two different `div`s and style the two divs separately. What I'm doing right now is fetching the chats and putting it in single div "messages" but I want to fetch the data as it and want to put it in two divs inside the "messages" div.

```
function fetch_chat() {
    // to fetch the chats between two users
    $.ajax({
        url: "fetch_chat.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            id: currentID
        },
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#messages").show();
            $('#messages').html(data);
            $("div.area").show();
            //chatTimer = setTimeout(fetch_chat, 500); //request the chat again in 2 seconds time
            if (!scrolled) {
                $("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
                scrolled = true;
            }
        }
    });
}   

<?php
require("config.php");
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "select * from users where id='$id'";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
$user_to = $row['name'];
$sql1 = "select * from chats where user_from='$_SESSION[name]' AND user_to='$user_to' OR user_to='$_SESSION[name]' AND user_from='$user_to' order by id";
$res1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
if (mysqli_num_rows($res1) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res1)) {
        echo $row['msg'];
    }
} else
    echo "No msgs <br />";
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

While fetching the data from database, if the message is from the user then give it a one class otherwise give it a different class. Then in the html file where you are displaying the chat results, define these class styles. Include these styles in the file in which you have the function fetch_chat(),

```
        <style>
        .mine {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }

        .notMine {
            background-color: lightyellow;
        }

    </style>
```

And the php would be

```
    <?php

    require("config.php");
    $id= $_POST['id'];
    $sql="select * from users where id='$id'";
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    $user_to= $row['name'];
        $sql1="select * from chats where user_from='$_SESSION[name]' AND user_to='$user_to' OR user_to='$_SESSION[name]' AND user_from='$user_to' order by id";
        $res1=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($res1)>0){
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res1)){
                    if($row["user_from"] === $_SESSION["name"] ) {
                        echo "<div class='mine'> $row[msg] </div>\n";
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "<div class='notMine'> $row[msg] </div>\n";
                    }
                    //echo $row['msg'];
                }
            }
        else {
            echo "No msgs <br />";     
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: But the session[name] is the name of the user who is currently logged in. So the if(userfrom == session (name) will always be true. I have tried this earlier and got the whole messages in same color

Comment: We are checking for each row - whether this row message is sent by the user or received by the user. - if($row["user_from"] === $_SESSION["name"] ) - So if this particular message is sent by the user then it would have different background.

Comment: Umm I think I am bit confused.... In my insert query I have inserted session(name) when the message is sent.and that's why the if statement will always be true in my case. Can you suggest me how to insert the name or Id of the user who sends it...

Comment: Insert into chats (userfrom, user to, msg) values ($_session[name], $user to, $msg) ;  this is my insertion query when someone sends a msg.

Comment: I think it the query is ok. You are fetching both types of records, where 'from' is this user as well as 'to' is this user. So I guess it should work.